# Create a rainfall raster with gstat or idw in R

Tags: r, inverse-distance-weighted, gstat

I am a beginner in R, I need to use gstat or idw function to get a rainfall raster, but I have an error in the formula. How can I change it?
This is my code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/A/Desktop/DatiPrecipitazioni/dati")
mydata<-read.csv(file="prova.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",dec=".",na="")

dataset<-read.csv(file="Dataset.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",dec=".",na="")

DTM=raster("DTM.tif")

vals<-mydata$HPrec

simplerasterPREC = function(dataset,DTM,vals){

 coordinates(dataset) = ~x+y

 proj4string(dataset)<- proj4string(DTM)

 idw_formula = gstat(id="vals",formula = as.formula(paste(vals,"~1")), data = dataset,nmax=10, maxdist=50000, set = list(idp=2)) 

 rast_int <- interpolate(DTM, idw_formula)

 rast_int <- mask(rast_int,DTM)

 return(rast_int)
}
```

If I see what happens line by line I have this error:

```
coordinates(dataset) = ~x+y

proj4string(dataset)<- proj4string(DTM)

idw_formula = gstat(id="vals",formula = as.formula(paste(vals,"~1")), data = dataset,nmax=10, maxdist=50000, set = list(idp=2))

Error in terms.formula(formula) : invalid term in model formula
```

Comment: Where comes `mydata`?

Comment: mydata is a csv file that contains the precipitation data and coordinates of the points where they are measured. It is in a folder on my desktop.

Comment: If `mydata` is the same one than `dataset`, change `vals` with `HPrec` in the function and try it. (`gstat(id="HPrec",formula = HPrec ~ 1, data = dataset,nmax=10, maxdist=50000, set = list(idp=2))`)

Comment: In dataset I have only coordinates, in mydata I have the coordinates and precipitation points. If I change vals with Hprec anyway it doesn't return rast_int. If I do (plot(rast_int)), I have this error:

Comment: I have an error: rast_int not found

Comment: dataset has two colums, x and y. This are my coordinates and they aren't longitude and latitude. mydata has three columns, x,y and HPrec.

Comment: Why are you wrapping this analysis in a function? It is really quite unnecessary.  If you are intending to use a function to automate the analysis you need to parse your variables correctly. I believe that your issue is in how you are defining your formula in relation to how "vars" is being parsed in the function. When writing a function, get the underlying code to work first, then wrap it in a function so that the errors do not get convolved. Have you run the idw model outside the function, without trying to paste the formula? Simple is a good place to start.

Comment: @Fabiana, three lines of your data will count for pages of explanations about how they are organized and it will help other users to use your question and eventually answer later

Answer (score 2):

I've done it like this:
first make a grid to which you'll interpolate your met station values,

```
library(gstat)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)

grd <- expand.grid(x=seq(from=bbox(met_stations)[1,1], to=bbox(met_stations)[1,2], by=0.05), 
                   y=seq(from=bbox(met_stations)[2,1], to=bbox(met_stations)[2,2], by=0.05))
coordinates(grd) <- c("x", "y")
gridded(grd) <- T
```

then you run the idw:

```
idw <- idw(formula =  your_rainfall ~ 1, locations = met_stations, 
           newdata = grd)
idw.output = as.data.frame(idw)  
names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("long", "lat", "var1.pred") 


ggplot() + geom_tile(data = idw.output, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = var1.pred))
```

Comment: If you look at the OP's code they are using the raster::interpolate function to make an estimate to a prediction grid. This is accomplishing exactly the same thing that you are outlining, in a simpler way using an existing raster extent and resolution. You really did not address the underlying issue at hand, which is not estimation to an array. The error is indicating an error in the formula call to gstat.